# Best way to make all tables read only

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2016 database of which I am the owner. It's an archive that's no longer accessible to anyone else. I still need to read this database by linking to it from other SQL Server databases and from Access.

I would like to be able to alter and create views in this database but I would like to prevent myself from inadvertently changing any data there.

What's the quickest, easiest, and easily reversible way to allow myself only select access to all the tables?

Comment: Create a user that only has `SELECT` and `ALTER VIEW` permissions on the database?

Comment: Put all the tables on a dedicated file group and mark that file group as READ_ONLY.

Comment: Create a database which contains only views with the views written to select data from you read-only database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alter database current set read_only
```

To reverse, or if you want to modify views, run

```
alter database current set read_write
```

No permissions-based solution is effective against the database owner.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up with doing.  The difference between this and a solution that keeps me from destroying data and simultaneously allows me to create/alter views is so miniscule as to not matter as it only takes a second or two to lock/unlock the whole database.  Thanks!